# Authorize.net Get Response from Server Integration Method

Tags: php, response, authorize.net

Suppose I have an Authorize.net form opened a pop-up of this form:

```
<?php
  $api_login_id = 'YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID';
  $transaction_key = 'YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY';
  $amount = "5.99";
  $fp_timestamp = time();
  $fp_sequence = "123" . time(); // Can be changed to an invoice or other unique number.

  $fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id, $transaction_key, 
$amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp);
?>
<form method='post' action="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">
  <input type='hidden' name="x_login" value="<?php echo $api_login_id?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $fingerprint?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $amount?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $fp_timestamp?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $fp_sequence?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_version" value="3.1" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_show_form" value="payment_form" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_test_request" value="false" />
  <input type='hidden' name="x_method" value="cc" />
  <input type='submit' value="Click here for the secure payment form" />
</form>
```

After customer has completed the form, and the payment is complete, how do i get the response from the form so I could check if payment is complete? Something like:

```
if ($response->approved) {
    echo "Success! Transaction ID:" . $response->transaction_id;
  } else {
    echo "ERROR:" . $response->error_message;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use [Relay Response](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536)

> Relay Response is a feature available to merchants using Server Integration Method (SIM) or Simple Checkout. It instructs the payment gateway to return transaction results to the merchant using an HTML form POST to a specified URL on the merchant's Web server. A script or program at the URL can be used to create a custom receipt page using the transaction information. The custom receipt page is then relayed back to the customer's browser. Relay Response does not redirect the end user back to the merchant’s server, but relays the page content to the end user instead of displaying the Authorize.Net default receipt page.

or [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/).

> Silent Post is an Authorize.Net feature that POSTs transaction data to a URL whenever a transaction is processed by them. It happens behind the scenes and allows a system to automate the handling of approved and declined transactions

I am the author of the Silent Post article as well as instructions for how to [implement it in PHP](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/).